# Express Gateway - Proxy request with Bearer Token

Tags: express-gateway

I am trying to figure out how to get Express Gateway to use the Auth Bearer token in request, upstream to the api service.

Below is my config as of right now.

```
http:
  port: 8080
admin:
  port: 9876
  host: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  api:
    host: localhost
    paths:
      - '/truck-api/*'
      - '/car-api/*'
serviceEndpoints:
  truck-service:
    url: 'http://10.0.0.2:5010/api'
  car-service:
    url: 'http://10.0.0.2:5011/api'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
  - rewrite
  - request-transformer
pipelines:
  default:
    apiEndpoints:
      - api
    policies:
      - proxy:
          -
            condition:
              name: pathMatch
              pattern: "^/truck-api/(.*)"
            action:
              serviceEndpoint: truck-service
              prependPath: true
              ignorePath: false
              stripPath: true
              changeOrigin: true
          -
            condition:
              name: pathMatch
              pattern: "^/car-api/(.*)"
            action:
              serviceEndpoint: car-service
              prependPath: true
              ignorePath: false
              stripPath: true
              changeOrigin: true
```

The frontend calls express gateway with a proper auth bearer token, however the express gateway doesn't forward that auth bearer token on to the upstream service.

Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging and a lot of trial and error the solution was relatively simple, use request transformer.

added this to the policies section:

```
      - request-transformer:        
        - action:
            headers:
              remove: ['Authorization']
              add: 
                Authorization: "'Bearer ***'"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me remove: ['Authorization'] did not work.
I was authenticating towards express gateway using:
`"Authorization: apiKey ${keyId}:${keySecret}"` and authenticating towards backend service by using Authorization: "'Bearer ***'" added by request-transformer. I would expect remove: ['Authorization'] would remove "Authorization: apiKey ${keyId}:${keySecret}", after I was already successfully authenticated at express gateway and add: Authorization: "'Bearer ***'" would add new Authorization header so newly constructed request would replace apiKey with Bearer token but using remove: ['Authorization'] resulted in failure to authenticate at express gateway.
I resolved this issue by changing HTTP header used for authorization at express gateway side with apiKeyHeader (https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/policies/key-authorization/).

```
 policies:
  - request-transformer:
    - action:
        headers:
          add:
        # pass oauth2 token
            Authorization: "'Bearer ***'"
  - key-auth:
    - action:
        # arbitrarily rename default header name from Authorization
        apiKeyHeader: open_sesame
```

The open_sesame header grants us access to api gateway and request-transformer adds authorization header with proper token to the request for accessing the backend service.

```
curl -v -H "open_sesame: apiKey ${keyId}:${keySecret}"...
```